# How can I tell what phase a plugin will run in?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using a plugin in my pom that looks like this:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- check for the latest version -->
                    <version>1.27</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>docs</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <docsDir>${project.build.directory}/docs</docsDir>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

And I'm wondering, if I run `package` will this plugin run or is it during `site` or something else?  Is there an easy way to tell by looking at this, or do I have to either

1. Read the plugin documentation
2. Experiment through trial and error

I'm hoping there's an easier way.  I'm using intellij-idea, if that provides a means I'd be happy with that.  Assuming I can't tell without one of these two methods, is it a best practice to always define the phase in the pom so that I can save myself and others time in the future?

Comment: It depends where we configure it is it in `<build>` or `<reporting>`. If it is configured in `<build>` will be executed during the build.

Comment: @Rp- That's not specific enough, I'm asking about which phase it will run in.  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html  I believe you told me which **lifecycle** it runs in, I'm asking which phase.  At least, that's my understanding of the vocabulary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let maven print out informations regarding the plugin using [mavens help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/examples/describe-configuration.html) - for enunciate simply use the following command:

`mvn help:describe -Dplugin=org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin -Ddetail`

It has actually 6 goals bound to different phases - goal `docs` will be bound to [`process-sources`-phase](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html)

To only extract the goal you are interested in you can furthermore use the following command:

`mvn help:describe -Dmojo=docs -DgroupId=org.codehaus.enunciate -DartifactId=maven-enunciate-plugin -Ddetail`

You could also omit the `-Ddetail` part, but it won't give you then any information on the phase it is running.